# I have created two 'raised buttons' but only one is showing. What is the problem here?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-design

I have made total 14 screens in the application, you may see in the code whose link i have provided below. Two raised buttons i have created, one button named 'Wonders of world' on pressing will take it to second screen the other button named 'wonders of India' will take it to eleventh screen. Unfortunately The first button wonder of world is not visible. Why it is not showing?
[This is the image on running the app, you can see only one raised button visible.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XO9IB.jpg)

[The link of the code](https://gist.github.com/ImVasav/6fbb99e2236cf1ff95a465bd8c1526e8)

Comment: I have read it, but i didnt get where should i put positioned widget , in the text or raised button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just wrap your both button in Row Like**

```
Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Text("Wonders of World"),
                  onPressed: (){
                    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SplashUI()));
                  },
                  color: Colors.red,
                  textColor: Colors.yellow,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
                  splashColor: Colors.grey,
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Text("Wonders of India"),
                  onPressed: (){
                    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => EleventhScreen()));
                  },
                  color: Colors.red,
                  textColor: Colors.yellow,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
                  splashColor: Colors.grey,
                )
              ],
            ),
```

Comment: its shwoing Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: Vasav Chaturvedi if @Deepak Ror   answer helped you, then you should upvote or accept it

Comment: when i click on the upvote icon, it gets upvoted but again get back to zero upvote and a message comes ' Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.'

Comment: don't worry @VasavChaturvedi, you have done your best.